# install MySQL 8 along with MariaDB in Linux Mint 19.2 (Tina)

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, linux-mint

I want to learn MySQL 8 but because of my work I cannot abandon MariaDB installed on my computer.
Is there any way that I can install both of them and use whichever I want according to my need?

Comment: One option is virtualization. Create an virtual machine with low resources and install `MySQL` on the virtual machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use docker for these kind of purposes.
You can also customize the port this runs on and change it to something else like 3360 in my.cnf

Comment: You don't even need to change the my.cnf, containers expose internal and external to a container in a mapping. Also consider [podman](https://podman.io/getting-started/installation.html#linuxmint-20x) as a rootless container runtime. Containers on multiple versions of mysql and mariadb can run at the same time

Comment: I am not so familiar with the concept of Docker.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).